# Add an image in the table (tabularx)

Tags: graphics, tabularx

I'm new to LaTeX, I have a table and I want to add an image in the first column of my table and I want that it fits a column. Can you give me some advice how to do it correctly?

```
\documentclass{article}     
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=1in]{geometry}   
\usepackage{ucs}    
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[russian]{babel}     

\pagestyle{fancy}    

\rhead{   
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X  X  X  X}    
\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth, height=15mm]{cat}&Класс документа: & Id  документа   & Название документа: \\

&Regulation       & 1        & СОП513                            \\

&Тип документа:   & № Версии документа: & Страница в документе:  \\   
&СОП              &  503   & \thepage                            \\    
\end{tabularx}    
}`    
\graphicspath{ {/home/Anton/} }    
\begin{document}
\noindent
hello world 
\end{document}
```

Here is what I have right now:

[[image]

Comment: change the first `X`  to `c` you want that column to fit its contents not (as X does) wrap the contents to a predetermined width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way, with a simple `\raisebox`. I also added `input encoding`, and had to change some parameters with `geometry`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=1in, headheight=73pt, includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\rhead{
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X X X X}
\raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth, height=15mm]{cat}}&Класс документа: & Id документа & Название документа: \\
&Regulation & 1 & СОП513 \\
&Тип документа: & № Версии документа: & Страница в документе: \\
&СОП & 503 & \thepage
\end{tabularx}
}%`
%\graphicspath{ {/home/Anton/} }

\begin{document}

\noindent Blah blah blah

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The upper border of the image is not in line with the upper border of the text. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: It isn't  since I designed it to be vertically centred.  To have it aligned at the top, uou can load `adjustbox`  withoption `[export]` and include the graphic file with a simpler `\includegraphics[valign=t]{graphic file}`.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is use `multirow` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}% <-- added multirow
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=1in, headheight=73pt, includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\pagestyle{fancy} 
\rhead{
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c X X X}%<--- see if "c" instead "X" column type is ok
\multirow{4}*{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth, height=16mm]{cat}}
    &   Класс документа:    &   Id документа        &   Название документа:     \\
    &   Regulation          &   1                   &   СОП513                  \\
    &   Тип документа:      &   № Версии документа: &   Страница в документе:   \\
    &   СОП                 &   503                 &   \thepage
\end{tabularx}
}%`
%\graphicspath{ {/home/Anton/} }

\begin{document}

\noindent Blah blah blah

\end{document}
```

[image]